# Can't get resteasy client to work

Tags: rest, maven, jboss, resteasy

I've tried many different ways to make the resteasy client work for me, but I'm stuck on an error.
java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/internal/ClientConfiguration

Here is the method I'm using as a client

```
    public void createIssue() {
    issue = new Issue();
    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("api-being-posted-to");
    Response response = target.request().header("Authorization: ", "Basic Foo")
            .post(Entity.entity(issueJson, "application/json"));
}
```

I can POST and GET with the same data this is using, and I've tried making a client work with different data and posting to different places and always get the same error. Here's my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId>
<artifactId>foo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>example</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

I'm using JBoss EAP 6.4 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as I can tell the provided version of resteasy in JBoss EAP 6.4 is 3.0.21.Final and not 3.1.0.Final but you might have modified that (see https://developer.jboss.org/thread/262213 for reference).
2. You use different versions and different scopes for your resteasy libraries (3.0.8.Final for jaxrs-api) but that might still be ok.
3. I would always recommend to use the [Resteasy Proxy Framework](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.21.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#d4e2301). It might be a bit more code to write but makes things easier and clearer in total:

Define an Interface:

```
public interface IssueIF
{
   @POST
   @Path("/issue")
   @Produces("text/plain")
   Issue postIssue(Issue i);
}
```

Use it:

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://example.com/base/uri");

SimpleClient simple = target.proxy(IssueIF.class);
Issue issue = new Issue();
client.postIssue(issue);
```

I did not compile this code, it is mostly copy/pasted from the docs but it should be close to what you need.

Edit:

From the [docs](http://Subclasses%20of%20LinkageError%20indicate%20that%20a%20class%20has%20some%20dependency%20on%20another%20class;%20however,%20the%20latter%20class%20has%20incompatibly%20changed%20after%20the%20compilation%20of%20the%20former%20class.):

> Subclasses of LinkageError indicate that a class has some dependency
>   on another class; however, the latter class has incompatibly changed
>   after the compilation of the former class.

This suggest that you have a problem with different library versions you use for compilation and on runtime so see above at no 1.

Especially if you use different scopes it is essential that the versions are the same for compilation and runtime! So try to find out which versions your JBoss supplies and only use these versions. Also find out which of your referenced libraries are supplied and mark all of them with scope provided.

Comment: What did you try?